# Generic delegate with different retun types

Tags: c#, delegates

I have some methods with different return types, like int and double.

But I try now to iterate over the different methods.

I try it like this:

```
delegate T MeDelegate<T>();
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int> d = ReturnFive;
            d += ReturnTen;
            d += ReturnTwentyTwo;
            d += returnDoubles;

            foreach (int i in GetAllReturnValues(d))
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.ReadKey();


        }

        static IEnumerable<TArgs> GetAllReturnValues<TArgs>(Func<TArgs> d)
        {

            List<int> ints = new List<int>();
            foreach (Func<TArgs> item in d.GetInvocationList())
                yield return item();


        }

        static int ReturnFive() { return 5; }
        static int ReturnTen() { return 10; }
        static int ReturnTwentyTwo() { return 22; }
        static double returnDoubles() { return 1.0; }

    }
```

and ofcourse this:  `Func<int> d`

doesnt work. But how to improve this?

Thank you

Comment: You can't.  The type of the func is set at compile time, and it isn't double.  Not sure what you're trying here, but if you have to do something like this, just return a type that encapsulates the return value and drop the generics completely.

Comment: you are just attaching events to d. you want to stuff d with the pointers to the function.

func<obj>[] d = new func<obj>[]  {ReturnFive, ReturnTen, ReturnTwentyTwo, returnDoubles };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you want or not, but try to use the below code.

```
delegate T MeDelegate<T>();
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<object> functionDelegates = ReturnFive;
        functionDelegates += ReturnTen;
        functionDelegates += ReturnTwentyTwo;
        functionDelegates += ReturnSomeDoubleValue;

        foreach (object value in GetAllReturnValues(functionDelegates))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IEnumerable<TArgs> GetAllReturnValues<TArgs>(Func<TArgs> functionDelegates)
    {
        return from Func<TArgs> function in functionDelegates.GetInvocationList() select function();
    }

    static object ReturnFive() { return 5; }
    static object ReturnTen() { return 10; }
    static object ReturnTwentyTwo() { return 22; }
    static object ReturnSomeDoubleValue() { return 1.0; }

}
```

Comment: @SavantCodeEngineer any reason not using `dynamic`

Comment: @AmitPore There's no reason *to* use `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

+= wires events. What you wanted to do was store them in an array.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<object>[] d = new Func<object>[] { ReturnFive, ReturnTen, ReturnTwentyTwo, returnDoubles };

            foreach (object i in GetAllReturnValues<object>(d))
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.ReadKey();


        }

        static IEnumerable<object> GetAllReturnValues<TArgs>(Func<object>[] d)
        {

            List<int> ints = new List<int>();
            foreach (Func<object> item in d)
                yield return item();


        }

        static object ReturnFive() { return 5; }
        static object ReturnTen() { return 10; }
        static object ReturnTwentyTwo() { return 22; }
        static object returnDoubles() { return 1.0; }

    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's use of `+=`.  All delegates in C# are multicast delegates, and as such can be combined as the OP did.

Comment: i didn't realize that when i wrote this but on the way home i started thinking about the += and invokeallinvocations and realized i am probably an idiot. thanks for confirming.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve but if you want functions with different return types , you can always you dynamic

```
List<dynamic> allReturns = new List<dynamic>{ ReturnFive(), ReturnTen(), ReturnTwentyTwo(), returnDoubles() };

 foreach (dynamic i in allReturns)
      Console.WriteLine(i);
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You're not actually using any of the features of `dynamic` here.  This code would do literally exactly the same thing if you used `object`, except it would run way faster as everything could be statically bound.

Comment: @Servy Thanks I understand  , just why write a delegate when it can be done in one line using 'dynamic' or 'object'

Comment: It's an example.  It's simply there to demonstrate the issue.  Presumably in the real code there is a good reason the methods cannot be just invoked once, immediately.  Perhaps they need a parameter that the invoking code provides, perhaps they're called multiple times, etc.  There are lots of reasons to use delegates, and including all of that in the question would likely just distract from the question being asked.